# Rails Engine processing wrong controller in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails engine ShoppingCart. I'm getting an error when I'm trying to access shopping_cart/order_items#destroy. In view ShoppingCart::Carts#show I have form that updates order_items. So I have:

```
- @order_items.each do |item|
  = form_for item, remote: true do |f|
    %td
      = link_to item, method: :delete, remote: true
```

But when I ran it, I got:

> Processing by ShoppingCart::CartsController#show as JS   Parameters:
>   {"locale"=>"en", "method"=>"delete"}

It is trying to find action destroy in wrong controller.
My routes:

```
ShoppingCart::Engine.routes.draw do
  resource :cart, only: %i[show update]
  resources :order_items, only: %i[create destroy update]
end
```

Also tried to use 'order_item_path' in view, but nothing new.

Comment: Check examples from [link_to docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Shouldn't it be `link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, remote: true`? Hint: for debugging, you may simply peek at generated HTML to see where the request will be sent.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, don't know how I have missed that.

Comment: No problem. Added as an answer as it seems correct, I'm never sure of Rails helpers syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Going through [link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) examples, this will be the correct way of writing your link:

```
link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, remote: true
```

`'Delete'` may of course be a different string of your choosing.